# problema con number() javascript

Tags: javascript

Alguien sabe por qué

```
Number(4444444444444444); // (tiene 16 cuatros)
```

da como resultado

```
4444444444444444
```

pero

```
Number(44444444444444444); // (tiene 17 cuatros)
```

da como resultado

```
44444444444444450
```

Comment: Trata de sumar  dos numeros de 17 digitos que la suma de un numero de 18 digitos y ve lo que pasa

Comment: Más bien, ya que eres tú el que pregunta, muestra el código que suma esos dos números... por eso te preguntaba y te pregunto **¿dónde?**. Cuando plantees una pregunta, muestra el escenario donde ocurre el problema.

Comment: Usando consola has esta operacion 44444444444444444 + 44444444444444444 y veras que no es correcto el resultado

Comment: Mira: `console.log(parseInt(44444444444444444,16) + parseInt(44444444444444444,16));` da como resultado: **`157412216095654840000`** no sé si es el resultado correcto.  Y `console.log(parseInt(44444444444444444,32) + parseInt(44444444444444444,32));` da como resultado: 
**`9.983387413591776e`**

Comment: El valor excede el máximo admitido : `Number.MAX_VALUE`. Ver [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: Lastima que esto sea un comentario y no una respuesta porque tu ultimo comentario es la respuesta que buscaba.

Comment: Elaboraré una respuesta, pero primero adapta tu pregunta al formato del sitio, así revertirás también los votos en contra que has recibido. Saludos.

Comment: @jufrfa buenas, he editado tu pregunta para que quedase en formato más entendible a la vista, espero que el resultado te parezca satisfecho. He votado positivamente la pregunta, quizá al ppo al no tener un formato muy legible ha podido llevar a confusión a alguien, pero a mi parecer, me parece una muy buena pregunta, y ahora queda más claro. Saludos.

Comment: Falta indicar los buscado/investigado sobre el tema. Referencia [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### El problema

El problema es que:

```
Number(44444444444444444);
```

1. **Excede el máximo admitido por Javascript** para el objeto `Number`. Existe una constante que calcula ese valor y la puedes obtener con:

   ```
   Number.MAX_VALUE;
   ```

De modo que si haces esto:

```
    var biggestNum = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    console.log("Máximo admitido: "+ biggestNum);
```

Obtendrás esto en pantalla:

```
    Máximo admitido: 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

2. Por el mismo motivo explicado en (1), `Number(44444444444444444)` **no es un *safeInteger*, es decir, no es un entero sobre el cual puedas operar sin riesgo de error**.

Para comprobar si un entero es seguro, Javascript cuenta con la función [`Number.isSafeInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)

De modo que si haces esto para verificar tu número:

```
    console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(44444444444444444));
```

Vas a obtener esto:

```
    false
```

3. Es más, el mismo máximo admitido para enteros en JS no es seguro. Si hacemos:

   ```
   console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(Number.MAX_VALUE));
   ```

Obtendremos:

```
     false
```

---

### La solución

Para operar con números grandes tienes dos salidas:

1. Implementar una librería de terceros que maneje bigInteger. Por ejemplo:

   - [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)
   - [javascript-biginteger](https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger)
2. Esperar a que Javascript incluye objetos BigInteger

---

#### Fragmento de código probando lo afirmado en esta respuesta

```js
//1. Máximo admitido
var biggestNum = Number.MAX_VALUE;
console.log("Máximo admitido: "+ biggestNum);


//2. 
tuNumero=Number(44444444444444444);
console.log("¿Tú número es safeInteger? "+Number.isSafeInteger(tuNumero));

// 3.
console.log("¿El máximo admitido es safeInteger? "+Number.isSafeInteger(biggestNum));
```

Answer (score 3):

El número más grande que puede ser almacenado (con precisión) en JavaScript es 9007199254740992. La razón por la que te devuelve 44444444444444450 es porque el motor de JavaScript hace un intento por representar y aproximar el valor proporcionado.

Entonces

```
Number(4444444444444444) = 4444444444444444 (OK, porque es menor al valor maximo permitido) 
Number(44444444444444444) = 44444444444444450 (WRONG, porque es mayor al valor maximo permitido)
```

Si es de tu interés revisa este link https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante para que comprendas a detalle como funciona la representación de los números.

Saludos
Juan Simón

Answer (score 3):

Según la documentacion de Number, Los Enteros (números sin una notación de período o exponente) son exactos hasta 15 dígitos.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Por ejemplo:

```
var x = 999999999999999;   // x sera 999999999999999
var y = 9999999999999999;  // y sera 10000000000000000
```